# Compare two words and return the number of letter differences

Tags: excel, vba

The macro is written to return the number of letter differences (insertions, replacements, or deletions) of two words (case sensitive).

It is suppose to format and output in phrases
1-2 Letters off,
1-2 Letters off, Same Starting Letter,
3-4 Letters off,
3-4 Letters off, Same Starting Letter and
5 or more letters off, CHECK

[image]

[image]

It is only outputting
1-2 Letters off, Same Starting Letter,
3-4 Letters off, Same Starting Letter and
5 or more Letters off, CHECK

I would like the formatting to stay the same for now.

```vb
Sub Test_HW_Formatter()
'declare the variables
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim testNames As Integer
Dim responses As Integer
Dim printRow As Integer
Dim name As String
Dim count As Integer
Dim coding As String
Dim statLetter As Boolean
Dim tempCount As Integer
Dim tempResp As String
'the queues for the entries, the respective counts, and respective codes
Dim words As Object
Set words = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")
Dim counts As Object
Set counts = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")
Dim codes As Object
Set codes = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")

'set the variables
printRow = 3
testNames = Selection.Columns.count
responses = Selection.Rows.count - 1

Cells(4, 3).Value = Selection(4)
startLetter = True
'make the header
Cells(1, 1).Value = "Name"
Cells(1, 2).Value = "Response"
Cells(1, 3).Value = "Count"
Cells(1, 4).Value = "Code"
Cells(1, 5).Value = "Agency close matches"
Cells(1, 6).Value = "N=" + Trim(Str(responses))
Cells(1, 6).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
Cells(1, 6).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
For i = 1 To 5
    Cells(1, i).Interior.Color = RGB(1, 139, 175)
    Cells(1, i).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Cells(1, i).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Next i

'get the information and put it in the queues
For i = 0 To (testNames - 1)
    name = Selection(i + 1).Value
    For j = 1 To responses
        count = 1
        If Not Selection(j * testNames + i + 1) = "" Then
            For k = 1 To (responses - j)
                If Not Selection((j + k) * testNames + i + 1).Value = "" Then
                    If Trim(UCase(Selection(j * testNames + i + 1).Value)) = Trim(UCase(Selection((j + k) * testNames + i + 1).Value)) Then
                        count = count + 1
                        Selection((j + k) * testNames + i + 1).Value = ""
                    End If
                End If
            Next k
            'get the coding
            coding = ""
            ld = Levenshtein(name, Trim(UCase(Selection(j * testNames + i + 1))))
        If Mid(testName, 1, 1) = Mid(sample, 1, 1) Then
            startLetter = True
        Else
            startLetter = False
            End If 'if for starting letter
            Select Case ld
            Case 0
                coding = "Exact Match"
            Case 1
                If startLetter = True Then
                    coding = "1-2 Letters off, Same Starting Letter"
                Else
                    coding = "1-2 Letters off"
                End If
            Case 2
                If startLetter = True Then
                    coding = "1-2 Letters off, Same Starting Letter"
                Else
                    coding = "1-2 Letters off"
                End If
            Case 3
                If startLetter = True Then
                    coding = "3-4 Letters off, Same Starting Letter"
                Else
                    coding = "3-4 Letters off"
                End If
            Case 4
                If startLetter = True Then
                    coding = "3-4 Letters off, Same Starting Letter"
                Else
                coding = "3-4 Letters off"
                End If
            Case Else
                coding = "5 or more Letters off, CHECK"
            End Select
            'enqueue the values
            tempResp = UCase(Mid(Selection(j * testNames + i + 1).Value, 1, 1)) + LCase(Mid(Selection(j * testNames + i + 1).Value, 2, Len(Selection(j * testNames + i + 1).Value)))
            words.enqueue (tempResp)
            counts.enqueue (count)
            codes.enqueue (coding)
        End If 'if the cell is not blank
    Next j
    'print the queues from the ith column
    'start the section header
    Cells(printRow, 1).Value = name
    Cells(printRow, 1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    For k = 1 To 5
        Cells(printRow, k).Interior.Color = RGB(1, 139, 175)
        Cells(printRow, k).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Next k
    tempCount = counts.count
    Cells(150, 20 + i).Value = tempCount
    For k = 1 To tempCount
        Cells(printRow + k, 2).Value = words.dequeue
        Cells(printRow + k, 3).Value = counts.dequeue
        Cells(printRow + k, 4).Value = codes.dequeue
        If Cells(printRow + k, 4).Value = "Exact Match" Then
            Cells(printRow + k, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(236, 239, 218)
        End If
    Next k
    printRow = printRow + tempCount + 2
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the `Levenshtein` function that gets the value for `ld`? If your output is incorrect, it seems to all hinge on the Select Case ld where ld may be incorrect.

Comment: I don't see the examples that are producing the incorrect results with regard to . Hard to tell the problem if we can't reproduce it.  So far as 3-4 letters off, you never test for the status of `startLetter`, so don't understand why you think it should be taken into account.   Also you could combine some of your `Case` statements (`1,2` and `3,4`)

Comment: You don't force the reference names to upper case, but do for the test/sample names - any reason? Or does case get normalized inside your Levenshtein function? Plus you really should use internal arrays rather than repeatedly going back to retrieve & process values from your spreadsheet.

Comment: I am sorry, I am a little new to programming. could you help me test for the startLetter? I also updated it slightly.

Comment: Levenshtein returns the number of letter differences (insertions, replacements, or deletions) of two words (case sensitive)

Answer (score 1):

Edited to add counting replicates of the same name, and skip empty values:

```vb
Sub Test_HW_Formatter()

    Dim arr, numReps As Long, ws As Worksheet, col As Long, c As Range
    Dim nm As String, rep As Long, cmp As String
    Dim i As Long, dict As Object, tmp
    
    arr = Selection.Value                    'inputs
    numReps = UBound(arr, 1) - 1             'reps per column
    
    Set ws = Selection.Parent                'sheet with selection
    With ws.Range("A1:E1")
        .Value = Array("Name", "Response", "Count", "Code", "Agency Close match")
        doHeaders .Cells
    End With
    ws.Range("F1").Value = "N=" & numReps
    
    
    Set c = ws.Range("A3")                   'start of output sections
    For col = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)            'loop columns of selection
        
        nm = arr(1, col)
        c.Value = nm
        doHeaders c.Resize(1, 5)             'format headers
        i = 0
        Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        
        For rep = 1 To numReps               'loop values to compare
            
            cmp = arr(rep + 1, col)
            If Len(cmp) > 0 Then
                If Not dict.exists(cmp) Then
                    i = i + 1
                    dict.Add cmp, i
                    c.Offset(i, 1).Value = cmp
                    c.Offset(i, 2) = 1
                    c.Offset(i, 3).Value = MatchCoding(nm, cmp) 'now in separate function
                Else
                    'increment count for existing line
                    c.Offset(dict(cmp), 2).Value = c.Offset(dict(cmp), 2).Value + 1
                End If
            
            End If 'not zero-length
        Next rep
        
        Set c = c.Offset(i + 2, 0) 'next set
    Next col
    
End Sub

'return a string summarizing how closeley two terms match
Function MatchCoding(nm As String, cmp As String)
    Dim ld As Long, firstMatch As Boolean
    firstMatch = (Left(nm, 1) = Left(cmp, 1))
                    
    ld = Levenshtein(nm, cmp)
    
    Select Case ld
        Case 0: MatchCoding = "Exact Match"
        Case 1, 2: MatchCoding = "1-2 Letters off"
        Case 3, 4: MatchCoding = "3-4 Letters off"
        Case Else: MatchCoding = "5 or more Letters off, CHECK"
    End Select
    If ld > 0 And ld < 5 Then MatchCoding = MatchCoding & _
            IIf(firstMatch, ", Same Starting Letter", "")
End Function

'utility sub for formatting headers
Sub doHeaders(rng As Range)
    With rng
        .Interior.Color = RGB(1, 139, 175)
        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I updated the above code. I know is is not the same but wanted to see where I am going wrong here? In your example are you combining the two statements?

Comment: I was adding something missing in your posted code, but you've now updated that, so the status of your question has changed it seems.  It would be useful for you to address that somehow.

Comment: Hi Tim, this still did not work. It is still outputting to only "1-2 Letters off, Same Starting Letter", "3-4 Letters off" or "5 or more Letter's off, CHECK".  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Try the edit above: comparing upper-cased initial letters

Comment: Should I keep my code in the question and just edit this? ld = Levenshtein(Name, Trim(UCase(Selection(j * testNames + i + 1))))
startLetter = ( UCase(Left(testName, 1)) = UCase(Left(sample, 1)) )

Comment: Hi Tim, I am made the change to the line and kept the remaining the same but now am getting an error at this line. End If 'if the cell is not blank after the "get the coding" portion of the code.

Comment: "an error" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code

Comment: Hi Tim I apologize for the lack of technical knowledge in this. I have update the script to what I currently have written and question. I appreciate the time you have taken on this. If you have time could you explain the change you recommend me make. I am not sure what you meant to change.  To give a little more detail, what I do is put a line of TestNames in Upper Case in Row one starting around column J and then a list of words to compare to below each name in Sentence Case. Everything seems to work fine except for differentiating between same starting letter and not same starting letter.

Comment: Any chance you can show a screenshot of  your worksheet?  What exactly is selected when you run your code?

Comment: I added the images. I highlight the two columns and run.

Comment: Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Updated my answer with a full example

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. This I believe fixed part of the issue but now it is not doing the counts and removing duplicates. Is it possible for you to help me fix this? Please see the two images I just attached. Also is it possible to keep it to where the listed names are in sentence case when we run it?

Comment: What is "count" supposed to represent?  Sorry I did not read your original code very thoroughly...   I don't know what you mean by "sentence case" - do you mean Proper Case?  But then your first row of names is all upper-case.

Comment: So count I mean the how many of the same responses are there and if there are duplicates delete them from the list. If you see my image above the the number of items is placed in the count column and the item is only shown once. In the list column under the test name duplicates are deleted. Yes, I would prefer to have to have the first row "Test Names" be UPPER and the listed words to be in Proper case if possible. This all worked in the previous code if that helps for reference. Again, this is all very helpful and very educational. Best.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Last thing I would like to do is make it to where Exact Match is highlighted green in the results. Could you help me add this? Also, is it possible to make it where we use proper case instead of UPPER case for the listed names? The top test names would be all caps and the listed names would be Proper case before we run?

Comment: Seems like that's something you could attempt  - add an `If Then` for the result from `MatchCoding(nm, cmp)` for the shading, and use `Application.Proper()` to convert the names to proper case.